# TSQL ORDER BY with nulls first or last (at bottom or top)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, isnull

I have a date column which has some `NULL`. I want to order by the date column ASC, but I need the `NULL` s to be at the bottom. How to do it on **TSQL**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server ORDER BY date and nulls last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886857/sql-server-order-by-date-and-nulls-last)

Answer (score 86):

In standard SQL you can specify where to put nulls:

```
order by col asc nulls first
order by col asc nulls last
order by col desc nulls first
order by col desc nulls last
```

but T-SQL doesn't comply with the standard here. The order of NULLs depends on whether you sort ascending or descending in T-SQL:

```
order by col asc -- implies nulls first
order by col desc -- implies nulls last
```

With integers you could simply sort by the negatives:

```
order by -col asc -- sorts by +col desc, implies nulls first
order by -col desc -- sorts by +col asc, implies nulls last
```

But this is not possible with dates (or strings for that matter), so you must first sort by is null / is not null and only then by your column:

```
order by case when col is null then 1 else 2 end, col asc|desc -- i.e. nulls first
order by case when col is null then 2 else 1 end, col asc|desc -- i.e. nulls last
```

Comment: +1 for calling out the standard vs. TSQL difference. `order by col asc` gives nulls first and `order by col desc` gives nulls last because SQL Server treats Null values as the lowest possible values, see [SELECT - ORDER BY Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

Comment: Love the sorting by negatives for integers!

Comment: It should be mentioned that the `case when` solution significantly negatively affects performance and should not be performed on large datasets. ([source](https://www.dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/sql-server/36-order-by-and-nulls-last-in-sql-server))

Comment: When doing the same for strings anyone think of anything nicer than: `CASE WHEN col IS NULL THEN 'ZZZZZZZ' ELSE col END`

Comment: Instead of `case when col is null then 1 else 2 end` the shorter `IIF(col IS NULL, 0, 1)` is also possible.

Answer (score 18):

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Order By case when DateCol is null then 0 else 1 end
         ,DateCol
```

Or even `Order By IsNull(DateCol,'2525-12-31')`

Comment: Make sure you log the extra code review you'll need to do in 500 years.  That technical debt can really add up!

Answer (score 3):

`order by case when col_name is null then 1 else 2 end, col_name asc` did the trick on Oracle. However the same on MS SQL Server pushes the NULL records down leaving non null to be on top of the result set.

Comment: Should be order by case when col_name is null then 1 else 2 end **DESC**, col_name asc in MS SQL and Oracle

Comment: Or order by case when col_name is null then **2** else **1** end, col_name asc

Comment: Simple. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me just now. Fortunately, I'm working with text. For anything numeric, I'd probably go with all 9's.
COALESCE(c.ScrubbedPath,'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'),

Comment: The original question is about sorting `date` values, not text, nor numeric values. Also, a generic, always applicable solution is usually preferred over hardcoded values like `zzzzz...`.

Comment: @Sander - Based on the question title, it is not unreasonable to treat the question more generically - how to sort nulls first or last, and the details about sorting by date are just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you may need to use a subquery to get this right:

```
 select site_id, site_desc
    from (
    select null as site_id, 'null' as site_desc
    union
    select s.site_id,
        s.site_code+'--'+s.site_description as site_desc
    from site_master s with(nolock)
    )x
    order by (case when site_id is null then 0 else 1 end), site_desc
```