# Sorting in SQL Server by two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have an `employee` table with below details

```
EMPid   TimeIn.             TimeOut
---------------------------------------------
123     1 Jan 2016 10:10    NULL
123     NULL                1 Jan 2016 18:30
123     1 Jan 2016 9:10     NULL
123     NULL                1 Jan 2016 18:00
```

I need output with order by time in ascending order. Below is sample output.

```
EMPid     TimeIn.              TimeOut
------------------------------------------------
123       1 Jan 2016 9:10      NULL
123       1 Jan 2016 10:10     NULL 
123       NULL                 1 Jan 2016 18:00
123       NULL                 1 Jan 2016 18:30
```

Comment: So what you tried that does not work? This is very basic question. Just look for `ORDER BY` clause in SQL.

Comment: @A_J both are in ASC order right?

Comment: It is just for sample. Time in or time out may be in any order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server ORDER BY date and nulls last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886857/sql-server-order-by-date-and-nulls-last)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @employee TABLE (EMPid INT,TimeIn DATETIME,TimeOut DATETIME)

    INSERT INTO @employee(EMPid,TimeIn,TimeOut)
    VALUES(123,' 1 Jan 2016 10:10',    NULL),
    (123,NULL,  '1 Jan 2016 18:30'),
    (123,' 1 Jan 2016 9:10'  ,   NULL),
    (123, NULL     ,           '1 Jan 2016 18:00')


SELECT * FROM @employee ORDER BY ISNULL(TimeIn,TimeOut)
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY TimeIn, TimeOut`