# SQL Query users set row number and last date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test3](
[UserId] [int] NULL,
[RoleId] [int] NULL,
[lastDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test3]([UserId],[RoleId],[lastDate])
VALUES
(1,1,'2019-02-02'),
(1, NULL, '2019-02-02'),
(1, 2, '2019-02-03'),
(2, 1, '2019-02-05'),
(2, 1, '2019-02-02'),
(2, 1, '2019-02-02'),
(3, 3, '2019-02-02'),
(3, NULL, '2019-02-02')
```

How do I set row number and max lastdate a list of users who have the same "userid"?
I need output should be look like this.

```
rownumber  userid   RoleId   lastdate
1          1        2       2019-02-03
2          1        1       2019-02-03
3          1        NULL    2019-02-03
1          2        1       2019-02-05
2          2        1       2019-02-05
3          2        1       2019-02-05
1          3        3       2019-02-02
2          3        NULL    2019-02-02
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I assumed it was `roleid`, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number` and `max` with [window functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/)

I think this bellow code can help you.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY RoleId DESC) AS ROWNUMBER,
   userid,
   roleid,
   MAX(lastDate) OVER(PARTITION BY userId) AS LAST
FROM   test3
```

Comment: Add `NULLS LAST` in the `ORDER BY` of the first line.

Comment: My bad. SQL Server does not implement NULLS LAST. Workaround is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886857/sql-server-order-by-date-and-nulls-last

Comment: @TheImpaler there is no need for NULLS LAST since the sorting is `ORDER BY RoleId DESC`.

Comment: @forpas My bad, just realised by default SQL Server considers nulls smaller than any other value. No need for `NULLS LAST` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` & `max()` with window function :

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by userid 
                          order by (case when roleid is null then 2 else 1 end), 
                                    roleid desc
                         ) as rowno,
       max(lastdate) over (partition by userid) as lastdate
from table t;
```

Comment: I always forget SQL Server does not implement `NULLS LAST`. Good one.

Comment: There is no need for CASE in ORDER BY. `roleid desc` is enough.